# in the year 2018 with API 27, how do I get the size of a file in android/java?

Tags: java, android

I want to know the updated correct answer with updated sdk.  My min SDK version is 24 and my target/compile version is 27.

How do you programatically calculate or get the size of a file in your android app?  I have seen people using .length of the file, but either that's not the whole picture or something is wrong or has changed.

Does .length need to be called only on the file after certain conditions are met?  Please provide a full example.

Comment: "either that's not the whole picture or something is wrong or has changed" -- please explain, in detail, what you feel is missing from the picture or what you feel has changed. "Please provide a full example" -- please edit your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you have tried and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: Still you can use that .length

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to confirm that .length works.  For a while though, I kept getting 0.  It may have been that the zip file was still being created.  I did ensure now though that I'm using async tasks to ensure that things are finishing first.

```
        String sPathToZip = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir() + "/" + "actual.zip";
        File theZipFile = new File( sPathToZip );
        if (theZipFile.exists()) {
            Log.i("zipFileExistTest", "zipped file actually exists and it's length is " + theZipFile.length());
        }
```